# Modular exponentiation in P

Tags: complexity-theory, number-theory

I need to prove that the following language is in $\mathsf{P}$:
$$ L = \{\langle x,y,z,d \rangle : xˆy \equiv z \pmod{d}\}.$$

I'm assuming I just have to prove with an algorithm or negate that it's part of NP. But I don't know how to do it with this mathematical formula.

Comment: No, the question was edited and its more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, anything in $P$ is also in $NP$, so proving that it's not in $NP$ will be an exercise in futility. I'm also going to change your variable names a bit to make them clearer; the letters I use stand for **b**ase, **e**xponent, and **m**odulus.

What you seem to be looking for is a *modular exponentiation* algorithm. In other words, a way to compute $b^e \mod m$ in polynomial time. Several of these exist, but here's the simplest one I know of:

```
function modular_exponent(b, e, m):
    z ← 1
    b ← b % m
    for i ← 1..e:
        z ← (b × z) % m
    return z
```

The number of multiplications and modulus operations we do is linear in $e$, and the operands to those operations are never larger than $m$. So the runtime is $O(e (\log{m})^2)$ (assuming multiplication runs in log-squared and modulus runs in logarithmic time; in practice you can make this even a bit more efficient using something like Karatsuba multiplication, but that doesn't matter for this problem).

This is clearly a polynomial runtime, so the modular exponentiation decision problem ("for given $b, e, m, z$, is $b^e\cong{}z \mod m$?") is in $P$.